# How to correct my unit test for GCD function

Tags: java, testing, recursion

I have written a simple GCD function to implement Euclid's algorithm for computing the greatest common divisor gcd(m, n), which is the largest integer k dividing both m and n.

The function that I wrote successfully compiles:

```
   public static int gcd(int m, int n) {
      if (n == 0) return m;
      return gcd(n, m%n);
   }
```

However, I run into an error when I write a unit test on GCD:

```
   @Test public void gcdTest() {
      for (int m = 0; m < 15; m++) {
      for (int n = 0; n < 15; n++) {
         assertEquals("Divide m,n", m/n%m, Recursion.gcd(m,n));
         }
      }
   }
```

The error comes in the 'assertEquals' line. I am unsure if maybe I am calculating this method incorrectly by writing m / n % m.

Any tips or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you start with 0 in both for-loops, you have a situation like 0/0%0.

Comment: @StefanFreitag Didn't even think about that! Now I start with 1 in both for-loops. However, I get an error saying Divide m,n expected 0, but was 1.

Comment: @Dday Hint: dont print "m, n" ... print the actual values of m and n. That message is supposed to **help** to identify those values that don't work! Then see my answer ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat Sweet, just got it! I'll accept your answer once I can, thanks!

Comment: You are more than welcome! And just for the record: when using expressions such as m / n % m ... of course, when one knows about the precedence of operators, the meaning of that expression is clear. But when you come back in a few days, you might be so sure any more. This means you will have to spend time thinking about it. So, just as an idea: consider putting ( braces ) ... not because they would be needed, but because they help you figuring what is going on quicker!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides the "math" thing here - using loops within unit tests is something that you should not do immediately.

What I mean is: before you think about testcases that **iterate** and do multiple asserts within a loop, do things like

```
@Test
public void gcdTest1_1() {
   assertThat(Recursion.gcd(1,1), is(1));
}
```

In other words: write simple testcases that test **one** thing only. And when the first one passes, write the next one. And then, when you are more confident, then consider such looping solution.

As that would might have given you that idea about dividing by 0 ... not being a thing to have in your tests!

Edit upon your comment: use see, the **core** idea of unit tests is that they help you find and fix bugs in your code under test. So looking at your example, the one big obstacle there is ... you are printing  a string "m, n". That doesn't tell you anything. You already know that your variables are called m and n. You better print the **values** of m and n in case the assert fails.

Finally: I changed to **assertThat**; some other style of assert, that I find to lead to "more readable" code. When using that, you will have to use hamcrest matchers such as *is()* though (google is your friend here).